# Rspec : Saving instance variable value on failure

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am testing a json based method. The method takes a json array list. The method works fine when the json array comes in a sequencial order and breaks when the array is randomized. It does not fail for all the randomized cases. So, on fail i want to save the value of the json array. Is there any way to do that?

```
describe 'when the flat hash comes in random order' do
  it 'knows how to create the parent nodes first' do
    do_stuff_and_validate(@flat_hash[:nodeList].shuffle!)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a custom matcher and override the failure message to display what you want.

The following example copied from the [RSpec docs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-9/docs/custom-matchers/define-matcher):

```
require 'rspec/expectations'

RSpec::Matchers.define :be_a_multiple_of do |expected|
  match do |actual|
    actual % expected == 0
  end
  failure_message_for_should do |actual|
    "expected that #{actual} would be a multiple of #{expected}"
  end
end

# fail intentionally to generate expected output
describe 9 do
  it {should be_a_multiple_of(4)}
end
```

Comment: Would the custom matcher be able to access to the local/instance variable?

Comment: Yes, if you passed it in to the matcher as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can write this array to the file to inspect it later.

```
File.open("hash.txt", 'w') do |f|
  f.write(your_json_array)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the begin-rescue-reraise trick.

```
begin
  # The assertions
rescue Exception => e
  pp @flat_hash
  raise e
end
```